# "I don't want to have to leave" what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

I've been listening to *Mutual* by Shawn Mendes and one line of the lyrics gets me confused, especially the "have to" part

> No I don't want to have to leave.
>   But half of you's not enough for me.

Do I want to stay nor not? Am I being asked to leave but I don't want to leave? Do I willingly want to leave?

[full lyrics here](https://genius.com/Shawn-mendes-mutual-lyrics)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting the next line, because that is actually the explanation for the first line.

It means something like this:

1. If I can only have half of you, I will leave.
2. I would prefer to have all of you and stay.
3. You won't let me have more than half of you.
4. Combining (1) and (3), I will leave.

The original puts this all much more concisely and poetically.

Answer (score 0):

It means they don't want to leave but if they have to leave then they will.